# How about "paper used in ancient Egypt to write and draw on" instead of "paper used in ancient Egypt for writing and drawing on"?

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

Below is an explanation of sense 2 meaning of the word, "papyrus", in Oxford English dictionary.

> paper made from the stems of the papyrus plant, used in ancient Egypt for writing and drawing on.

I wonder whether it is also okay to change the above explanation into the below.

> paper made from the stems of the papyrus plant, used in ancient Egypt to write and draw on.

Thank you.

Comment: Either the _gerund_ ("writing" and "drawing") or the _infinitive_ ("to write and (to) draw") is acceptable here.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Thank you for the explanation as always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your sentences would be understood to mean the same thing.

However there is a difference. Your first sentence

> ...used ... for writing and drawing on.

means *something* is used *on* the papyrus, whereas

> ...used ... to write and draw on.

could be interpreted as the papyrus is being used "to write and draw", but anyone who knows what papyrus is would know that is usually not done.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Peter. But what you mean is that the second one could be interpreted wrongly? But there is "on" at the end of it. I thought to myself that with "on" at the end of it there is no possibility that it could be misunderstood. Can you teach me about this?